# Javascript - object code required

Tags: javascript

Our JavaScript code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://hosted.musesradioplayer.com/mrp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
MRP.insert({
'url':'http://streams.museter.com:8002/;',
'codec':'mp3',
'volume':65,
'autoplay':true,
'buffering':5,
'title':'Radio%20Vermont',
'welcome':'WELCOME TO...',
'bgcolor':'FFFFFF',
'skin':'mcclean',
'width':180,
'height':60
});
</script>
```

This code shows error message on IE. Error message "object code required". 
How to fix this issue? Any one knows?

Comment: On what line are you getting error? you can see it using developer tools. Also, is it running fine in other browsers?

Comment: On other browsers working fine. Only IE shows this error

Comment: The problem is probably in mrp.js. You should contact the guys of http://www.musesradioplayer.com/ if their tool is still maintained

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a version of IE that does not support HTML5 (IE8 or earlier), the muses radio player requires a flash object solution. You can get this from the muses site http://www.musesradioplayer.com/setup. If you are using IE9 or newer, it should support the HTML5 solution.

Comment: To get the <object>, you have to choose "I want to host the player and skin files on my server. " And, obviously, add the player and skin files to your server.